# delete button on unbound gridview - C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, gridview

Can anyone tell me how to fire the sql delete command on a gridview which is unbound?
Is shows the result of a LINQ search and I have AutoGenerateDeleteButton as true but Im not sure how to link this to a delete query.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the Delete button is hit, the RowCommand Event of GridView fires, and there you can check it by Command Name like.. `e.CommandName == "Delete"`

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        // Put your Deletion code here.....     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Insert, Update, and Delete Operations (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx) topic showing how to implement these operations using LINQ.

Comment: Im comfortable enough using LINQ, its the firing it via the delete button on the unbound gridview Im not sure of...

Comment: Sorry, it seems I did not understand your question ... and do not understand it now :-(.  Could you please clarify it?

Comment: no problem - I have an unboud gridview populated with a LINQ query after the user clicks a search button.  I would like a delete button on the gridview to work the same way as it would on a gridview bound to a sql datasource with the update and delete queries specified.  I have set the AutoGenerateDeleteButton to true, so how then do i link the user clicking this to a LINQ delete query?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code Theresa, hope it helps.

```
private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           DBConnDataContext db = new DBConnDataContext();
           tbWellClassification shortName = TableGrid.SelectedItem as tbWellClassification;
           var well = (from s in db.tbWellClassifications
                       where s.shortName == shortName.shortName
                       select s).Single();
           db.tbWellClassifications.DeleteOnSubmit(well);
           db.SubmitChanges();

           MessageBox.Show("Row Deleted Successfully.");

           txtStatus.Text = "Row Deleted";

           db = null;
           DBConnDataContext db2 = new DBConnDataContext();
           TableGrid.ItemsSource = db2.tbWellClassifications;

           TableGrid.Items.Refresh();
       }
       catch
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Delete Unsuccessful");
       }

   }
```